# import pyodbc in Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, pyodbc, azure-webjobs

just wonder is there a way to use pyodbc in a python WebJob

I want to set up a scheduled web job which will periodically fetch data from Azure database

However there's always error loading the pyodbc module, even if I upload the compiled version and add path in my script. anyone knows how to use pyodbc in an Azure WebJob?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the error message received when attempting to load the module.

Answer (score 1):

**Get the working PyODBC :**
To use PyODBC you should compile it in its 32bits version (very important) with Python 2.7 or Python 3.4

Or install Python 2.7 or 3.4, 32bits, and type the command **"pip install pyodbc"**

**Use in Azure WebJob**
Put the PyODBC.pyd file in the root directory of your job and it should work.

**Note :**
If your PyODBC library isn't in a 32bits version, you should have the error *"... Not a valid Win32 application"*